# Questdb authentication for web console?

Tags: questdb

I'm trying to add authentication to questdb web ui, as I don't want it to be exposed to the public internet. But it seems there are no options out of the box?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ?

Comment: @Jicao at the moment we are proxy for auth in front QuestDB console.

Answer (score 1):

There is no authentication available on the web console yet out of the box, so the most common options are to:

- set up an auth proxy in front of the instance using nginx or similar
- disable the web console and REST API [via server configuration](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration#http-server)
- set the instance to read-only (`http.security.readonly`) via HTTP

Comment: Could you explain how to setup an auth proxy with apache server (Ubuntu) ?